# Apply ParallelMap to function f over a matrix while passing as arguments the row number and the element index

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, parallelization, list-manipulation

I have a matrix `test = { {2.5,1.4,3.3},{4,4,4},{7,3.2,9}}` and a function `f` that requires 2 arguments, the row number and the index of the element inside the row, and I want to `ParallelMap` the function over the matrix to speed  up the computation ( the matrix can be very long, over 30k elements) .how would you achieve this result and what is the fastest method available?
the result should be :

```
result = {{f[1,1],f[1,2],f[1,3]},{f[2,1],f[2,2],f[2,3]}, {f[3,1],f[3,2],f[3,3]}}
```

closest thing I have achieved is :

```
 ParallelMap[
 MapIndexed[f[1, #2[[1]]] &    ,   #[[2]]       ] &,           
 Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, test}]                  ]
```

but it fails when I try to change the row number from 1 to #[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVUkV.jpg)]

[image]

Comment: no in this case i get `{ {f(1,1),f(2,2),f(3,3)},{ f(1,1),f(2,2),f(3,3)}
{f(1,1),f(2,2),f(3,3)}}` which  is not what i need

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish. I guess I would do it with `Compile` and the options `RuntimeAttributes -> Listable` and `Parallelization -> True`. Also, many built-in functions are vectorized, so for example `Sin[test]` is so fast that you won't beat it by `ParallelMap`.

Comment: I cannot understand what you want to get, especially, the part `result = ......`.

Comment: i need to compute the autocorrelation at every step t   from the magnetization array  for 3 different temperatures ( the 3 rows of the array) .  to apply the correct formula  i need to know the element index  and the row  number. the row number is fundamental because i must replace the values in the correct row to not mix up the data. to use Listable i think i have to build a new matrix with elements {{1,1},{1,2},{1,3}...} etc , and i was trying to avoid it

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ it was just an example of what i wanted to achieve: the four kernels should work in parallel on the 4 temperatures and switch the data in the correct place. my example matrix has 3 rows but in truth it's 4x30000 array

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher uhm i think you gave me the right idea... maybe  there is no need to build a new matrix update: no i think it necessary, i need to sum over the entire row from index y to the end

Comment: `ParallelMap[
 Module[{x = #[[1]], y = #[[2]]}, MapIndexed[f[x, #2[[1]]] &, y]] &, 
 Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, test}]]`?

Comment: @kglr yes thank you! i have updated the question  with a picture from the book i am following. the objective is to apply that formula for each row

Comment: For tasks such as in snapshot from the book, the functions `ListCorrelate` and `ListConvolve` should we worth a look. These methods are also faster as you can ever be with `Compile` (believe me, I tried several times ^^); probably because they have optimised memory access at a level that is hardly achievable through the `Compile` keyhole.

Comment: @Alucard But how is `result` related to your `test` matrix, I cannot see anything, other than the `Dimension`.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ  the function f takes 2 more arguments other then the position, I simplified it  in the example. the shape of the matrix is not fixed and it is not a square matrix most of the tines, my function replace the elements of the initial matrix with the corresponding value of the correlation. I am sure there are other methods to achieve the same result, this is just the first one I found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParallelMap[Module[{x = #[[1]], y = #[[2]]}, MapIndexed[f[x, #2[[1]]] &, y]] &, 
  Transpose[{{1, 2, 3}, test}]];
% == result
```

> True